# How do I address a very specific web url?

Tags: c++, html, web, ip, ip-address

I am writing code in C++ (using the Poco net libraries) to try to create a program for fun which will email me every few hours with updates to the TwitchPlaysPokemon stream (stupid, I know).  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>   
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketStream.h"
#include "Poco/StreamCopier.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Poco::Net;
using namespace Poco;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    string url = "www.reddit.com";

    string fullPage;
    SocketAddress sa(url, 80);
    StreamSocket socket(sa);
    SocketStream str(socket);
    str << "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
     "Host: " << url << "\r\n"
     "\r\n";
    str.flush();

    StreamCopier::copyStream(str, cout);    
}
```

This exact code works perfectly fine.  It grabs the raw html of `www.reddit.com` and prints it to the console.  However, I'm trying to get information from one of two places for my program:

Either:

[Here](http://www.reddit.com/live/sw7bubeycai6hey4ciytwamw3a) (url = "http://www.reddit.com/live/sw7bubeycai6hey4ciytwamw3a")

or

[Here](https://sites.google.com/site/twitchplayspokemonstatus/) (url = "https://sites.google.com/site/twitchplayspokemonstatus/")

Either of these will be fine for my purposes.  The problem is that when I plug these values in as the url in my program, the program has no idea what I'm talking about.  Specifically, I get the following:

[image: Unhandled Exception]

so clearly it cannot find the host.  This is where I am stuck, as I know very little about internet protocol, hosts, etc.  I tried to see if there was a specific IP address for this website (using cmd prompt ping), but it couldn't figure it out either ( it says "Ping request could not find the host www.reddit.com/live/sw7bubeycai6hey4ciytwamw3a"). The Poco library accepts written out urls (www.reddit.com), IPv4, and IPv6 addresses as the host input to SocketAddress (where I use the variable url, the other variable is the port which I've been told should basically always be 80?)

***Question***: I need help figuring out how I should be identifying the host to the Poco library.  In other words, how do I properly refer to the host for either of those two sites listed above in such a way that my code can recognize it and grab the HTML from the page.

Comment: Try to figure out the "case" when that exception is thrown. From your code it seems that HostNotFound is thrown on several different cases. Can you browse those links from browser on the same machine where you execute your application?

Comment: I have no idea what specific case is causing my exception.  If I hit continue instead of break, a few exceptions I run into are `throw DNSException("EAI", NumberFormatter::format(code));` , then `throw DNSException("Temporary DNS error while resolving", arg);`, and finally `throw DNSException("Non recoverable DNS error while resolving", arg);`.  Not sure if these are sort of a domino effect or if theyre all mutually exclusive exceptions (obviously the last two are related)

Comment: Do you use full URL when you create SocketAddress object? You're supposed to use only website address in there, and use full URL when issuing GET request. You're passing full URL to SocketAddress constructor, that's why it gives you error

Comment: @mangusta I just used www.reddit.com for the URL and the full address for the "Host: " section, and it appears to have given me the html for the reddit main page, not the page I'm looking trying for.

Comment: No, You're issuing "GET / ". You should issue "GET /<your url> "

Comment: Should be "GET /live/sw7bubeycai6hey4ciytwamw3a HTTP/1.1" and then "Host: www.reddit.com:80"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though you may not understand HTTP correctly. Here's a brief refresher.

To get the contents of the URL `http://www.example.com/path/page.html`, the corresponding HTTP request would be sent to `www.example.com` on port 80, and would have the contents:

```
GET /path/page.html HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.example.com\r\n
\r\n
```

The critical part that it doesn't look like you're doing correctly here is splitting the URL into the hostname and path components. Having a single `url` variable won't work (unless you manually split it on the first slash).